# Equation for symmetric graph that rises and levels off

Tags: graphing-functions

Trying to fine-tune a particular growth pattern needed for a game. In short, for player level 1 to MAX, they need to be able to acquire $y$ resources per level $x$. So $y=f(x)$. So we're talking about a shape similar to $y=\log(x)$, but the requirements are a smooth curve with:

1. If $x < \frac{MAX}{2}$, the graph rises with a decreasing slope
2. At $x = \frac{MAX}{2}$ (the midpoint) the slope is 1
3. If $x > \frac{MAX}{2}$, the graph rises with an increasing slope
4. The graph is **symmetrical** around $\frac{MAX}{2}$
5. $y>0, (-\infty,\infty)$.

The intent is to have $Y$ level off with a limit we can declare in order to avoid higher level players getting excessive rewards. The symmetry should be around a $45^\circ$ angle from $y = x$ (top-left to bottom-right). In other words, think "upper left quadrant of a circle", but being able to push or pull along the circle's radius at the midpoint of the arc.

The two variables we'd like to be able to tune are the rate of growth (how fast the slope decreases and increases around $\frac{x}{2}$) and the limit.

I know this should be dead simple, but I've stumbled on it :)

**Update** Because I am apparently rubbish at describing this, this image and description might help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeMkq.jpg

Comment: By MAX you mean the global maximum, right? Also, what do you mean by fine-tune the limit?

Comment: By "MAX" I mean "Maximum level the players are (currently) allowed to have". By "limit" I mean "Y must not exceed this amount." Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: So the player's level is a function of the resources they acquire?

Comment: Yes. `resources = f(level)`

Comment: 4) Symmetrical about which axis?

Comment: Think "the arc of the upper left quadrant of a circle" and symmetrical along the radius from the origin (center of the circle) to the midpoint of the arc.

Comment: I'm not sure your requirements are not self-contradictory then. You can't get a curve that's symmetrical about such origin unless your whole boundary area is also symmetrical about that axis, which means that y must be always equal to MAX.